# Multiple transaction in appCtx encountered NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I am working on Spring MVC based web application in which I have two datasource, for which I need to maintain two transactions `**DataSourceTransactionManager**`,

I did nothing, just copied my `EXISTING Txn` transaction snippet and modify it according to the other datasource, have a look please at my

**app-ctx.xml**

```
<!----- EXISTING Txn-------->
     <bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        </bean> 
     <!----- NEWLY ADDED Txn-------->   
        <bean id="erptransactionManager"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourcePayroll" />
        </bean>
```

Now the **service class**, where exactly I need to use.

```
package com.awzpact.prayas.service;

import com.awzpact.prayas.dao.HRMSPickSalaryDataDAO;
import com.awzpact.uam.domain.SalaryDetailReport;
import com.awzpact.uam.domain.Userdetail;
import com.awzpact.uam.exceptions.MyExceptionHandler;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionDefinition;

/**
 *
 * @author jack
 */
@Service
public class NewPayrollService {

    final TransactionDefinition erpTxnDefination = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    final TransactionDefinition prayasTxnDefination = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    final int BATCH_SIZE = 500;

    public void getSalarayData(final String yearMonth, final String regionId, final String circleId, final Userdetail loginUser) {
        final String tableSuffix = yearMonth.substring(4, 6) + yearMonth.substring(0, 4);
        final TransactionStatus erpTransaction = erpTransactionManager.getTransaction(erpTxnDefination);
        try {
            List<SalaryDetailReport> list = hRMSPickSalaryDataDAO.findAll(yearMonth, regionId, circleId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        final TransactionStatus prayasTransaction = prayasTransactionManager.getTransaction(prayasTxnDefination);

    }

    @Autowired
    DataSourceTransactionManager prayasTransactionManager;

    @Autowired
    DataSourceTransactionManager erpTransactionManager;

    @Autowired
    HRMSPickSalaryDataDAO hRMSPickSalaryDataDAO;
}
```

**ERROR LOG**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'newPayrollService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager com.awzpact.prayas.service.NewPayrollService.prayasTransactionManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: transactionManager,erptransactionManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4020)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.reload(ManagerServlet.java:1012)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:381)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager com.awzpact.prayas.service.NewPayrollService.prayasTransactionManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: transactionManager,erptransactionManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: transactionManager,erptransactionManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 46 more
```

I am not able to figure it out, I isolate the `bean id` as, also I refer the other `datasource` i,e `dataSourcePayroll`.

Please let me know best solution to achieve this, or is there any alternate solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways is to specify name of your beans

```
<bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" name="oldOne">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        </bean> 
     <!----- NEWLY ADDED Txn-------->   
        <bean id="erptransactionManager"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" name="newOne">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourcePayroll" />
        </bean>
```

and then use a Qualifier

```
package com.awzpact.prayas.service;

import com.awzpact.prayas.dao.HRMSPickSalaryDataDAO;
import com.awzpact.uam.domain.SalaryDetailReport;
import com.awzpact.uam.domain.Userdetail;
import com.awzpact.uam.exceptions.MyExceptionHandler;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionDefinition;

/**
 *
 * @author jack
 */
@Service
public class NewPayrollService {

    final TransactionDefinition erpTxnDefination = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    final TransactionDefinition prayasTxnDefination = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    final int BATCH_SIZE = 500;

    public void getSalarayData(final String yearMonth, final String regionId, final String circleId, final Userdetail loginUser) {
        final String tableSuffix = yearMonth.substring(4, 6) + yearMonth.substring(0, 4);
        final TransactionStatus erpTransaction = erpTransactionManager.getTransaction(erpTxnDefination);
        try {
            List<SalaryDetailReport> list = hRMSPickSalaryDataDAO.findAll(yearMonth, regionId, circleId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        final TransactionStatus prayasTransaction = prayasTransactionManager.getTransaction(prayasTxnDefination);

    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("oldOne")
    DataSourceTransactionManager prayasTransactionManager;


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("newOne")
    DataSourceTransactionManager erpTransactionManager;

    @Autowired
    HRMSPickSalaryDataDAO hRMSPickSalaryDataDAO;
}
```

Comment: You just nailed it @Aleydin, thanks so much mate, but do me a favour, can you tell me what exactly the problem is ?

Comment: The problem is that Spring does not know which of the two beans to pick, because you have two beans of type `DataSourceTransactionManager`. Specifying name of the two beans of type `DataSourceTransactionManager` and telling which you want (using @Qualifier) does not confuses Spring anymore

Comment: 1+ for very useful information, thanks so much Aleydin, btw, ur name resembles with Aladdin :), hope u dn mind :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are given different bean id in bean definition and you are using that property with different name. So Spring container is not able to identify which one bean assign for `prayasTransactionManager`  and `erpTransactionManager` ..

The solution is use same bean id for bean definition which is used as Property name .
in your case :

```
<!----- EXISTING Txn-------->
 <bean id="prayasTransactionManager"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    </bean> 
 <!----- NEWLY ADDED Txn-------->   
    <bean id="erpTransactionManager"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourcePayroll" />
    </bean>
```

or use like this with your old code.

```
  @Autowired
@Qualifier("transactionManager")
DataSourceTransactionManager prayasTransactionManager;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("erptransactionManager")
DataSourceTransactionManager erpTransactionManager;
```

P.S : The best practice to give bean id and property name (Dependency) use camelCase pattern with meaningful names.